# Grouping Weeks in Netezza to start on Wed and end on Tues

Tags: netezza

I need the grouped weeks that I have listed as what week they are in the year to be grouped starting 73 days ago and beginning on Wednesday and ending on a Tuesday...can this be done?

```
Select  date_part('week',b.INV_DT), sum( a.ORD_QTY) as Ordered, sum( a.SHIPPED_QTY) as Shipped
from fct_dly_invoice_detail a, fct_dly_invoice_header b, dim_invoice_customer c
where a.INV_HDR_SK = b.INV_HDR_SK
and b.DIM_INV_CUST_SK = c.DIM_INV_CUST_SK
and a.SRC_SYS_CD = 'ABC'
and a.NDC_NBR is not null 
and b.inv_dt between CURRENT_DATE - 73 and CURRENT_DATE
and b.store_nbr in (2851, 2963, 3249, 3385, 3447, 3591, 3727, 4065, 4102, 4289, 4376, 4793, 5209, 5266, 5312, 5453, 5569, 5575, 5892, 6534, 6571, 7110, 9057, 9262, 9652, 9742, 10373, 12392, 12739, 13870
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake a week starting Wednesday and ending on Tuesday by subtracting two days.

```
Select  date_part('week',b.INV_DT -2), sum( a.ORD_QTY) as Ordered, sum( a.SHIPPED_QTY) as Shipped
from fct_dly_invoice_detail a, fct_dly_invoice_header b, dim_invoice_customer c
where a.INV_HDR_SK = b.INV_HDR_SK
and b.DIM_INV_CUST_SK = c.DIM_INV_CUST_SK
and a.SRC_SYS_CD = 'ABC'
and a.NDC_NBR is not null 
and b.inv_dt between CURRENT_DATE - 73 and CURRENT_DATE
and b.store_nbr in (2851, 2963, 3249, 3385, 3447, 3591, 3727, 4065, 4102, 4289, 4376, 4793, 5209, 5266, 5312, 5453, 5569, 5575, 5892, 6534, 6571, 7110, 9057, 9262, 9652, 9742, 10373, 12392, 12739, 13870
```